# Android Application launches with wrong resolution

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, screen-resolution

So I've been building an Android Application, and wrote a lot of code before actually testing it in a virtual or real device. The first time I tested it was in a Nexus One virtual device. It ran fine. Problem is, since then, the app launches with the exact same resolution for Nexus One in every other device, virtual or not. I tried launching it on a Nexus 4 (VD), Nexus 7 2013 and 2012 (VD) and a real device Acer Iconia A1-830. The Views and ActionBar all appeared "zoomed" as if it was filling the screen with the Nexus One resolution, and I have no idea why this happens, or where I can change that setting (if there is one).
Screenshot of app running in Nexus One:
[image: running in nexus one]

Screenshot of app running in Nexus 4 (Similar in 7 and in the real device it's even more noticeable):
[image: running in nexus 4]

Granted it doesn't look very different in these screenshots, but it is scaled wrong.

My MainActivity layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.tinkerstudio.todolist.gui.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_insert_todo_txt"
        android:id="@+id/btn_insert_todo"
        android:onClick="insertTODOBtnClicked"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listview_todo_list"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_insert_todo" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

dimens.xml are both in default settings

w820dp:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Example customization of dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml
         (such as screen margins) for screens with more than 820dp of available width. This
         would include 7" and 10" devices in landscape (~960dp and ~1280dp respectively). -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

"regular":

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not reported, this seems to be a bug in Android Studio
Remaking the project solved the issue.